# How to add dynamic number in Twilio SMS API PHP

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

How can I add and Send SMS to number dynamically by PHP code.

I have add number from admin panel and send SMS to this static number. It works, but if I want to add number from HTML form. So how can I register number dynamically by PHP code.

```
$message = $client->messages->create(
   '+919711969920', // Text this number
   array(
     'from' => '(205) 358-4782', // From a valid Twilio number
     'body' => "Hello Sudhir"
   )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely take input from an HTML form. Rather than hard coding the number into your PHP you would need to retrieve the number you want to send the message to from the incoming request parameters.

You could do this with:

```
$message = $client->messages->create(
   $_REQUEST["to"],
   array(
     'from' => '(205) 358-4782', // From a valid Twilio number
     'body' => "Hello Sudhir"
   )
);
```

Make sure your form then has an input field with the name "to" and when you submit the form you will be able to get the parameter from the request with the code above.

```
<input type="tel" name="to" id="to" />
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking there? What do you want to do?

Comment: Right now I am using trial version. In trial version dynamic number generates error.

Comment: Ah, that is because in the trial version you can only send messages to numbers that you have verified in your account. If you want to send messages to any number you need to upgrade your account.

Comment: Thanks for your response